# Memory leak of ServerIdentity objects generated by AppDomain proxies?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, .net-remoting

**Problem**
*TLDR;* I am seeing a steady leak of `ServerIdentity` objects for each transparent proxy object I create.

I am generating AppDomains as a mechanism to sandbox some 3rd party code execution, and utilizing `MarshalByRefObject` and `appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap()` to generate a transparent proxy to execute my code. However each instance I marshal also creates a corresponding `ServerIdentity` that is apparently held onto by an internal static class.

**What I've tried**

1. Unloading the `AppDomain` via `AppDomain.Unload(appdomain)` disconnects and cleans up the `AppDomain` instance, but the `ServerIdentity` objects remain and accumulate.
2. Calling `RemotingServies.Disconnect(marshalbyrefobject)` throws an exception as it apparently isn't for handling transparent proxies since it throws this error: `System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: 'Cannot call disconnect on a proxy.'`

The closest I've come to finding an answer to this was this [blog post](https://nbevans.wordpress.com/2011/04/17/memory-leaks-with-an-infinite-lifetime-instance-of-marshalbyrefobject/) describing a very similar issue. However there must be additional context to their code that I am missing.

**dotMemory Screenshots**

*Number of new objects increases with each request, does not get garbage collected*
[image]

*ServerIdentity instance key retention paths*
[image]

**Edit 1**
So I discovered what was causing the exception mentioned in bullet point number 2. Basically you can't call `RemotingServices.Disconnect(proxyInstance)` from the main AppDomain. It has to be done on the real `MarshalByRefObject` instance object created in the secondary `AppDomain`. Basically I created my own abstract implementation of `MarshalByRefObject` like so. **I verified that `Disconnect()` is being called for each marshaled instance.**

```cs
public abstract class SandboxedInstance : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public sealed override object InitializeLifetimeService()
    {
        // This override implementation ensures the lifetime of this object until Dispose() is called.
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method called internally when containing Sandbox is disposed, automatically disposing this object.
    /// </summary>
    internal void Disconnect()
    {
        RemotingServices.Disconnect(this);
    }
}
```

However, this has not solved my problem. The `ServerIdentity` objects still seem to be lingering around despite `RemotingServies.Disconnect(marshalbyrefobject)` successfully being called. Is there anybody who understands the guts of whats going on? I can find very little documentation on this.

**Edit 2**
Is there anybody who can confirm this theory? I've read mentions that some remoting objects live past the point of `Disconnect()` but are eventually cleaned up. Based on this theory I ran dotMemory and watched to see if ServerIdentity objects were cleaned up over time, especially ones retained via `Lease`. This actually seems to be the case. Can anyone with knowledge on this issue confirm this?

Comment: I think I might be experiencing the same, as I'm seeing a lot of ServerIdentity instances living beyond a point I would no longer expect them. Did you eventually find out whether there was a memory leak?

Comment: I’m going by memory here as it’s been a few years now, but by virtue of watching what the memory was doing over time it seemed like the instances were possibly not getting cleaned up until 2nd gen garbage collection. I just remember that the overall memory usage remained stable over longer periods of time even though the objects remained after a regular garbage collection.